# Exponent for non-linear regression (in R)?

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression

I have a non-linear reglationship and I want to find the best way to determine the value for the exponent $\gamma$ in the following regression:

$y = \beta x ^ \gamma$

I would preferably like to do this in R.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "best" and on the nature of your data. For example, if $y$ is measured with additive error then really $y = \beta x^\gamma + \varepsilon$, which is nonlinear, but if $y$ is measured with *multiplicative* error then $\log(y) = \log(\beta) + \gamma \log(x) + \delta$ is actually a linear model. *The two models are not the same*: typically they will produce (slightly) different estimates of $\gamma$ and different standard errors. If also $x$ is measured with error, both models get substantially more complicated and yield yet two more estimates.

Answer (score 4):

In order that this receive an answer (though it may not add a heck of a lot to whuber's comment):

> I want to find the best way to determine the value for the exponent $\gamma$ in the following regression: $y = \beta x^\gamma$

The observed $y$ will not actually be $\beta x^\gamma$; if it were there'd be no need for statistics.

We might say $E(y)=\beta x^\gamma$, for example, but it's not sufficient.

To address this problem we would normally consider the distribution of $y$ given $x$, and describe how the distribution - or at least parameters that describe the distribution, such as at least the mean and variance - relates to $x$.

In particular, we would (at least) consider the way the error term enters the relationship, such as:

$y=\beta x^\gamma+\varepsilon\,$, or

$y=\beta x^\gamma\times\eta$

If it's of the first form, and the (zero-mean) error terms are independent with $\text{Var}(\varepsilon)$ constant, then we'd use ordinary nonlinear least squares to estimate $\beta$ and $\gamma$.

If it's of the second form, and the error terms are independent, $\eta$ is positive (such that $\log(\eta)$ is zero mean and constant variance), then we might take logs and estimate $\beta$ and $\gamma$ using linear regression.

If, on the other hand, we assumed that the $\eta$ were gamma-distributed, then we might fit a gamma-family GLM with log-link.

In some situations, it doesn't make sense to specify an error term at all; consider the situation where $y\sim \text{Poisson}(\beta x^\gamma)$; the specification $E(y)=\beta x^\gamma$ is correct, but to deal with things from there we're best leaving the model as $y\sim \text{Poisson}(\beta x^\gamma)$. Again, this would be fitted via a GLM with log-link.

There are a number of other possibilities.

If you really do need the nonlinear regression option (additive error, constant variance), then this is done using `nls` in R.

This works a little differently to `lm`, because `lm` can simply assume one coefficient for every predictor. By contrast, `nls` needs us to specify the form of the model including the parameters.

---

Here's an example (the data comes with R. It isn't necessarily suited to this model).

```
carsfit=nls(dist~beta*speed^gamma,data=cars,start=list(beta=exp(-.73),gamma=1.6))
```

The `start` values came from an OLS regression on the logs of the y and x variables.

```
 summary(carsfit)

Formula: dist ~ beta * speed^gamma

Parameters:
      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
beta    0.5897     0.3357   1.757   0.0853 .  
gamma   1.5493     0.1920   8.068 1.74e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 15.06 on 48 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 3 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 4.979e-07
```

[image]