# Poisson regression VS log-linear regression VS linear regression with log transformation

Tags: regression, poisson-regression

Could someone explain the differences among the three? It looks to me the function form is the same so they're doing the same thing, but the potential assumption on Y distribution is different between 1 and 3. And I think 1 and 2 is exactly the same thing.

1. Log Transformations on Y in a Linear Model
2. Log-linear regression
3. Poisson regression

Comment: Can you define what you intend by log-linear regression?

Comment: This post may be of some relevant to you: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47870/exponent-for-non-linear-regression-in-r/108989#108989 - I think there's a better one but I can't locate it right now